# Should HTTP/REST web APIs be always async?

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it a good practice to always have `ASP.NET Core Web API` controllers and action methods `async`? What are the pros and cons? Is there any guideline as such?

(Note: We have some class libraries which are referenced in the Web APIs. The class libraries use `async` `await` extensively and it spreads everywhere.)

Answer (score 3):

If the action method calls an asynchronous method, then it should be `async`.

If it does not call an asynchronous method then it should not.

The purpose of an action method being `async` is that asp.net can release the thread to serve other requests whilst the asynchronous work is happening.

It increases throughput, rather than improving the performance of a single request.

However, `async` does add (minimal) overhead so should be avoided when the code is actually synchronous.